# Use of the common English abbreviation for German term

Tags: german-to-english, abbreviation

In my text I have a German term "Entscheidungsbaum" for which there is no common abbreviation. Much better known is the English term "Decision Tree" and its abbreviation "DT".

My first approach was to write the English term and the abbreviation in brackets behind it:

> Ein Entscheidungsbaum (englisch: Decision Tree (DT)) ist ein binärer Baum...
>
> ... Der Einsatz von DTs ist für Klassifikations- und Regressionsprobleme geeignet.

Afterwards I would always use "DT" in the following text to refer to it.

Is this legitimate?

Comment: Ich würde nicht Klammern in Klammern benutzen, sondern  „ (englisch: Decision Tree, DT)“ schreiben.

Comment: Why not just use Entscheidungsbaum? It's only one word.

Comment: @TonyK because very likely this 17-letter-word will be used several times in the text. It is very natural that one does not want to type such a long word more than two or three times in an article, on the other hand, frequent use of copy-paste would interrupt one's typing-flow.

Comment: So wie Du die engl. Abkürzung selbst einführst kannst Du auch eine dt. Abk. einführen: "Ein Entscheidungsbaum (i.F.: EB, englisch: Decision Tree) ist ein binärer Baum... - i.F. steht für `im Folgenden`.

Comment: @CarstenS Vielen Dank, die innere Klammer hat mich auch gestört. Würdest du wie von „user unkown“ noch ein „i.F.“ vor das „DT“ setzen: „(englisch: Decision Tree, i.F.: DT)“?

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf   It may have been "natural" in the times of mechanical typewriters to try to use abbreviations for repeating lengthy words. I do not see a need in the times of word processors. Abbreviations, especially custom ones (i.e. to which the reader is not accustomed), are likely to be a nuisance for the reader.

Comment: I guess "DT" is a well-known abbreviation in English. I have never seen a German abbreviation for "Entscheidungsbaum", therefore I would use the English standard and not create something like "EB".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Copy+Paste hilft aber auch nur so lange, bis Du es zwischendurch mal für was anderes brauchst, danach unterbricht das Zurückgehen, Wort markieren und StrgC den Schreibfluss ebenfalls erheblich. Und als Leser wäre ich ggf. sogar irritiert, wenn auf aufwändiges Wort, das in jedem dritten oder vierten Satz vorkommt, vom Autor **nicht** irgendwie abgekürzt würde.

Comment: @Volker Landgraf: der übliche Ausweg ist die Suchen-und-Ersetzen-Funktion, also einfach mit DT schreiben und dann am Ende ersetzen. Für bessere Lesbarkeit würde ich in einem richtigen Artikel auch so weit wie möglich ausschreiben, wie es ja zum Beispiel auch der Wikipedia-Artikel zu dem Thema vorbildlich tut. Stichwortnotizen sind natürlich was anderes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is this legitimate?

Specifically for techincal / scientific documentation it's legitimate, yes.
Especially if the technical / scientific fields *main or major language is English*.

Comment: When you have to introduce an abbrevation not known to the reader (here: DT), you would better introduce an abbrevation in the language of your text. For *Entscheidungsbaum*, why not use *EB* (after spelling the word fully at its first occurrance)?